# How to run SQL files via PowerShell

Tags: sql, powershell

I need to run a set of SQL queries which include update and insert statements.

My PowerShell commands keep failling:

```
commands = f'Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "{query}"'
output = execute_powershell(settings.PORT1, settings.USER1,
                                settings.PASSWORD, commands)
```

An example for a query I have:

```
update [tableA] set [columnC] = '{Json values here}' where [columnD] like '%someValue%'
```

My commands keep failing because my queries are very long and also contain special chars like & @ $ and #.

How can I run a SQL file via PowerShell that is on my server?

Comment: I suggest please read https://www.sqlshack.com/working-with-powershells-invoke-sqlcmd/

Comment: Test the Queries in SQL Server Management Studio where the error message are much better.

Comment: The single quotes in your queries need to be escaped by replacing with two single quotes and putting entire string in a single quote : 'update [tableA] set [columnC] = ''{Json values here}'' where [columnD] like ''%someValue%'''